# Additional endpoints auto-generated for REST API

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm currently developing a REST API for school project, so far everything was fine. We only are at the beginning of it, but we face some difficulties:

The `/` route gives us a list of endpoints, and thus we discovered some other unknown endpoints: `/users`, `/profile`.

I never created such endpoints, and are probably auto-generated by Spring Security or whatsoever

Here is what I get from the / endpoint

```json
{
  "_links" : {
    "users" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8081/users{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "kits" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8081/kits{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "carts" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8081/carts{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8081/profile"
    }
  }
}
```

Security configuration:

```java
package com.cetm.fabtrack_backend.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.context.DelegatingSecurityContextRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.context.RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class GlobalSecurity {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .securityContext((securityContext) -> securityContext
                        .securityContextRepository(new DelegatingSecurityContextRepository(
                                new RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository(),
                                new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository()
                        ))
                )
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
            UserDetailsService userDetailsService,
            PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);

        return new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider);
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

`pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.cetm</groupId>
    <artifactId>fabtrack_backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>fabtrack_backend</name>
    <description>backend project for fablab</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Do you have any idea of how to get rid of those endpoints? Or at least from where they come? I know I could disable them with some kind of `requestMatcher("/users").denyAll()` but I feel it is not the proper way to do it and I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you have got these endpoints is in your maven `pom.xml` file because you have imported next one dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

And this one according to [documentation](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-rest/)

> Spring Data REST is part of the umbrella Spring Data project and makes
> it easy to build hypermedia-driven REST web services on top of Spring
> Data repositories.

Generate rest apis for you, based on entities and repositories

To get rid of it you have to remove above dependency from `pom` file, that’s all